# phpunit avoid truncated output

Tags: console, phpunit

How can I avoid phpunit testing output being truncated:

```
1) Tests\ApiTest::testGetMetricList
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException: Server error: `GET http://localhost/micobe/myproject_p4/index.php/investors/get_metric_list` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response:
<br />
    <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-exception' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr (truncated...)


    /var/www/html/landing-myproject-page/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:113
    /var/www/html/landing-myproject-page/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php:65
    /var/www/html/landing-myproject-page/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:203
    /var/www/html/landing-myproject-page/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:156
    /var/www/html/landing-myproject-page/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/TaskQueue.php:47
    /var/www/html/landing-myproject-page/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:246
    /var/www/html/landing-myproject-page/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:223
    /var/www/html/landing-myproject-page/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:267
    /var/www/html/landing-myproject-page/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:225
    /var/www/html/landing-myproject-page/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:62
    /var/www/html/landing-myproject-page/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php:131
    /var/www/html/landing-myproject-page/app/Http/Controllers/ApiController.php:171
    /var/www/html/landing-myproject-page/tests/ApiTest.php:31
```

Comment: I doubt that PHPUnit truncates here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you experienced the difficult task to debug the **(truncated...)** error message through PhpUnit  see below global solution !

The exception caught is related to the **guzzle version**

> A try-catch around your phpunit test would get the GuzzleException $e

**Example**

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://foo.com/api/']);

```
try {

    $response = $client->request('GET','/v1/testYourEndpoint');

} catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientErrorResponseException  $e) {

    var_dump($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents());

} catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $e) {

       print_r($e->xdebug_message);
       var_dump($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents());

} catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException  $e) {

    var_dump($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Guzzle truncated the output, not PHPUnit. If you're using Laravel you can use `dd($response->getBody());` to get the full output.